# Does equality of push-forward of measures imply equality of measures?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is very well known that if I have two measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ on a measure space $X$ and I have a map $f \colon X \to Y$ (being $Y$ another measure space) such that 
$$
f_{\#} \mu_1 = f_{\#}\mu_2
$$
(as measures in $Y$) then one ***cannot*** conclude in general that $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

What I am wondering about is something a bit different.

> In the framework above, assume you have a map $f \colon \mathbb R \times X \to Y$ such that $t \mapsto f(t,\cdot)$ is non-constant (to avoid trivialities) and
>   $$
> f(t,\cdot)_{\#} \mu_1 = f(t,\cdot)_{\#}\mu_2, \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb R
> $$
>   (again equality as measures in $Y$).
>
> **Question**. Does it follow $\mu_1 = \mu_2$?

I suspect the answer is *not* but I am not able to figure out a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Might be still trivial) Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be any measure on $X$ with $\mu_1 (X) = \mu_2(X)<\infty $ and $\gamma :D \to Y$ be any map. Then
$$f : D\times X \to Y, \ \ F(t, x) = \gamma (t)$$
satisfies that $f(t, \cdot)_\sharp \mu_1 = f(t, \cdot)_\sharp \mu_2 = \mu_i(X) \delta_{\gamma(t)}$ for all $t\in D$ but $\mu_1$ might not be $\mu_2$.

For a somewhat less trivial example: Let $X = Y = \mathbb R$, $\mu_1 = \delta_{-1}$, $\mu_2  =\delta_{1}$ and 
$$f(t, x) = e^t x^2.$$
Then for all $t$, 
$$f(t, \cdot)_\sharp \mu_1 = f(t, \cdot)_\sharp \mu_2 = \delta_{e^t}. $$

Comment: Nice reply, thanks. So actually I should also assume that $x \mapsto F(\cdot, x)$ is non-constant: this would rule out your counterexample, right? Which would be the answer in that case? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Romeo : Please see the edit.

Comment: Yes, you got it, I am very convinced now. Thank you very much.